Equals node for compositor
I'm trying to compare two scene renders to find the difference between them, the simplest thing I can imagine would be an 'equals' maths node but that doesn't exist, wondering if anyone has a solution for this.
Without an equals node, my next thought would be to just find the difference with a less than and a greater than node, but as you can see this doesn't work. The less than than node reads most of the parts of B that are identical to A as less than (I have double checked and there are definitely much larger identical sections of the images, they are shaded just with a flat colour).

The compare maths node is close but really not at all precise.
I imagine this problem would be pretty easy to solve with a custom node but I'm hoping I can solve this without having to install an older version of blender :/
Here are two renders for reference (not sure why one is huge here they're the same size) ->


In compositor, math nodes work on float values, not vectors and colors, so you have to split the 3 components and perfom operations on each of them.
The compare node seems to perform what you're looking for, ugly results come from ugly input data (noise and size differences).
If you want to isolate objects for compositing purposes, you'd better use materials, ID and cryptomatte masks instead.


Yeah i dont mind just working with the bw values, i still don't understand why the compare node doesn't register some parts of the image as identical? But yeah i might try to work something out with cryptomatte masks thanks for the suggestion
